# Keycloak SPI: Access pasword in getUserByUsername

Tags: keycloak

In Keycloak I implemented a custom UserLookupProvider and a CredentialInputValidator. The legacy system which I want to get connected to keycloak is only able to check if a user exist if I supply the system with the user ID and the password.

Unfortunately I dont have access to the password in the getUserByUsername function. Therefore I cant check if the user exists in the legacy system.

I found this similar question without an answer: https://lists.jboss.org/pipermail/keycloak-user/2019-May/018271.html

Comment: `UserStorageProvider` interface doesn't have the `getUserByUsername` method, do you extend the [`LDAPStorageProvider`](https://www.keycloak.org/docs-api/8.0/javadocs/org/keycloak/storage/ldap/class-use/LDAPStorageProvider.html) and, if so, is your legacy system LDAP based? Please, specify it in the question as it seems to be relevant for your issue.

Comment: Sorry I mean "UserLookupProvider"

Answer (score 1):

I found an answer:

I've found the idea here [How to implement Recaptcha on keycloak login page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46974448/how-to-implement-recaptcha-on-keycloak-login-page) (https://github.com/raptor-group/keycloak-login-recaptcha/blob/master/src/main/java/org/keycloak/marjaa/providers/login/recaptcha/authenticator/RecaptchaUsernamePasswordForm.java)

I created a UserNamePasswordForm

```
public class RecaptchaUsernamePasswordForm extends UsernamePasswordForm implements Authenticator{

    @Override
    protected Response createLoginForm( LoginFormsProvider form ) {
        return super.createLoginForm( form );
    }

    @Override
    public void authenticate(AuthenticationFlowContext context) {
        super.authenticate(context);
    }

    @Override
    public void action(AuthenticationFlowContext context) {
        context.getSession().setAttribute("password", context.getHttpRequest().getDecodedFormParameters().get("password").get(0));
        super.action(context);
    }

}
```

I can access the password now everywhere:

```
 @Override
    public UserModel getUserByUsername(String username, RealmModel realm) {
        session.getAttribute("password")
        if (isAuthenticatedInUls(username,session.getAttribute("password"))) {
            return migrate(username, username, realm);
            //
        }
        return null;
    }
```

Comment: How did you achieve this, for me RecaptchaUsernamePasswordForm is not called at all. I've registered the class using services file name of Authentication Factory.

Comment: You can enable this in the Keycloak admin ui

Comment: Yes, I've enabled it in User Federation, The UserProvider is getting invoked but not the RecaptchaUsernamePasswordForm. Hence session.getAttribute("password") is coming as null.

Comment: I did manage to get it working. Sad part is we need to add customize Authentication Flow, without which we can't get it working

Answer (score 0):

in KC 22 you can get password from http params inside Provider by `session.getContext().getHttpRequest().getDecodedFormParameters().getFirst("password")`